# Pass manually generated RecordSet to SubReport

Tags: ms-access

In Microsoft Access 2007 is it possible to manualy generate a RecordSet object and pass the object to a Microsoft Access Report and Sub Report?

I would like to have a Form, on which the user clicks a button and the OnClick event  dynamically creates two RecordSets, opens a Report and attaches the first RecordSet to the Report and the second RecordSet to a SubReport on that Report.  And then generates/shows the report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Record Source of a form or a report to an SQL string. You can also filter a form or report based on an exiting query or table using the WHERE argument of OpenForm or OpenReport. Finally, you can set the recordset of a form to an existing Recordset, but that is slightly more complicated that just setting the Record Source to sql.

```
  sSQL = "SELECT [" & Me.AField & "] FROM [" & Me.ATable & "] " _
       & "WHERE [" & MeAnotherField & "] " & Me.Operator & Me.Value

  Forms!AnotherForm.Recordsource = sSQL
```

Disconnected recordset

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset ''CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")

 With rs
    'Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
 End With

'Create arrays from the lists
asL1 = Split("a,b,c,", ",")
asL2 = Split("b,e,c,d", ",")

'Create a disconnected recordset
rs.Fields.Append "Srt", adVarChar, 25
rs.Fields.Append "L1", adVarChar, 25
rs.Fields.Append "L2", adVarChar, 25

rs.Open

'Add list 1 to the recordset
For i = 0 To UBound(asL1)
    rs.AddNew Array("Srt", "L1"), Array(asL1(i), asL1(i))
    rs.Update
Next

rs.Sort = "Srt"

Set Me.Recordset = rs
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I did not ask the question clearly.  For the sake of clarity, I don't have any tables in the database.  I want to manually/programatically create a ADODB.RecordSet using VBA.  Then I want to attach the RecordSet to the Report.  I am trying to avoid generating a temporary table, populating it and then deleting it.

Comment: I had the wrong properties. The above is tested, however, you may not be able to use a disconnected recordset for a report.